# LibreOffice page numbering

Tags: libreoffice

How can I add the page number in LibreOffice so it appears from a specific page to another in the top right corner.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add page numbers, or are you meaning something more specific?

Comment: Yeah page numbers. the one that goes typically in the upper right corner to know in what page you are on.

Comment: Like this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhIO1H_a_vs

Comment: Yes Chris but I need for the numbering to start from a specific page.

Comment: I wish someone would answer the question in intelligible English. What is "click into the first paragraph" supposed to mean? Clink where? Select? Select all? And what is "just to enable" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Inserting a page number]

**1** - Select **Insert**

**2** - Select **Fields**

**3** - Select **Page Number**

This is from the LibreOffice documentation: [Starting With A Defined Page Number](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers)

[image: To Start With a Defined Page Number]

Comment: Thank you scouser but now I need for the numbering to start from a specific page.